# How to store maps api key in local.properties and use it in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, api-key

I am using Jetpack Compose and trying to integrate Google maps in my application. I have followed the documentation in setting up an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key). However, I am getting an error when building the project. On my `local.properties` file I have the following code:

```
MAPS_API_KEY=my_api_key
```

And on my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.guidemetravelersapp">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.GuideMeTravelersApp">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
    <activity
        android:name=".homescreen.HomeScreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GuideMeTravelersApp.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".registerview.RegisterView"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_view"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GuideMeTravelersApp.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ExperienceDetailsView.ExperienceDetailsActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_experience_details"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GuideMeTravelersApp.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginView.LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GuideMeTravelersApp.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GuideMeTravelersApp.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But, this seems that it is not enough, because I get the following error when building the project to see the preview:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.example.guidemetravelersapp.homescreen.MapViewUtilsKt.getMapLifecycleObserver$lambda-2(MapViewUtils.kt:60)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
at com.example.guidemetravelersapp.homescreen.MapViewUtilsKt$rememberMapViewWithLifecycle$1.invoke(MapViewUtils.kt:48)
at com.example.guidemetravelersapp.homescreen.MapViewUtilsKt$rememberMapViewWithLifecycle$1.invoke(MapViewUtils.kt:45)
at androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffectImpl.onRemembered(Effects.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl$RememberEventDispatcher.dispatchRememberObservers(Composition.kt:781)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges(Composition.kt:639)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:733)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2980)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2980)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:259)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.access$subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:145)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:234)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:231)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:49)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1107)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:231)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:226)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose$ui_release(SubcomposeLayout.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:466)
at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:314)
at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:241)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:357)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:925)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:56)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:901)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:94)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:186)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:125)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:925)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:56)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:901)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:94)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper$measure$1$1.placeChildren(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper$measure$1$1.placeChildren(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:393)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:266)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:221)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:220)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper$measure$1$1.placeChildren(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:186)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:125)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:925)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:56)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:901)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:94)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:186)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$5.invoke(Box.kt:167)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$5.invoke(Box.kt:163)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:925)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:56)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:901)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:94)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper$measure$1$1.placeChildren(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:186)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:125)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:357)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:925)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:56)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:901)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:94)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:359)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:179)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:632)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:631)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer-aW-9-wM(Placeable.kt:396)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:151)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelativeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:385)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelativeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:246)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy$measure$2.invoke(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:43)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy$measure$2.invoke(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:42)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:925)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1788)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:119)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:56)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:915)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:901)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:94)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper$measure$1$1.placeChildren(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper$measure$1$1.placeChildren(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper$measure$1$1.placeChildren(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:111)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:359)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:179)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.place$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:803)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:213)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure_Original(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:547)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt)
at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:25466)
at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25430)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:278)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure_Original(ComposeView.android.kt:265)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt)
at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:25466)
at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:25466)
at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:25466)
at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25430)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:25466)
at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:25466)
at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25430)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:673)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureLayout(RenderSessionImpl.java:256)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:368)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

When I check the `local.properties` file it gives me a warning that the `MAPS_API_KEY` is not used. I am not sure how i can use it. I followed what the documentation says, but it is not working.
For the map code I am trying to adapt the [Crane sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Crane) to my project, which has a Google map.

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine yes, I already did those steps. I have an account and I already got my API key, I put `my_api_key` here on stackoverflow as to not share my actual API key.

Comment: Did you place the `meta-data` at the correct place ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine yes, under the application tag, correct? I added the whole code of the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this in your app module's `build.gradle`, in the `defaultConfig` closure:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        Properties properties = new Properties() 

        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        manifestPlaceholders = [MAPS_API_KEY: "${properties.getProperty('MAPS_API_KEY')}"]
    ...
    }
}
```

And add this meta data in your manifest:

```xml
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"      
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

[Here](https://github.com/sitatec/Go4Lunch) is a project example on Github.

Comment: under the android{} section? @sitatech

Comment: unfirtunately, it didn't solve the error, and I am still getting the warning in the `local.properties` file :( @sitatech

Comment: hmm it still says that the property is not being used and throwing that error. I will take some time to check your project on github. @sitatech

Comment: The Exception is caused by the absence of the google play services version metadata, adding it in your manifest should solve it. Try cleaning your project and Gradle cache after adding the metadata and then rebuild it.

Comment: I am no longer getting the error I described above. However, I am getting another one. Not sure if I have to create a new question to show this new error. @sitatech

Comment: If the errors are different, yes you should create another question and mark this one as solved if it is.

Comment: hmm the thing is I am not quite convinced it solved, since I am still getting that warning in `local.properties` stating that `MAPS_API_KEY` is not being used.

Comment: the warning in your `local.properties` will not disappear because you are not directly referencing the `MAPS_API_KEY` in your app (you can't), you are using the `Property` instance to load it (the code you have added to your `build.gradle`.  That warning will not cause your app to crash. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: ok I see. In that case I marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Bro that was pretty much given in the logs. If you read them

Comment: I mean that is why they are created isn't it? For developers?

Comment: Yes you are right @MARSK the `google_play_services_version ` meta-data was given in the error's message.

Answer (score 5):

> In your local.properties

```
MAPS_API_KEY=your_key_here_do_not_wrap_in_quote
```

> Module level build.gradle

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        manifestPlaceholders = [googleMapsApiKey: "${properties.getProperty('MAPS_API_KEY')}"]
    }
}
```

> And finally in your AndroidManifes.xml

```
<application
   

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${googleMapsApiKey}" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answer is an update as of March 2024;
I'll start over, step by step

In your **local.properties** file, add your api key, without quotes:

```
MAPS_API_KEY=apikeyexampleX3mUz3umlsWfUQjZFcQPT0iBV_xok
```

In your **app module** *build.gradle.kts*, set your key in default build configuration:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.example.app"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.app"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        // load local.properties file
        val properties = Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").inputStream())
        // Set API keys in BuildConfig
        buildConfigField("String", "MAPS_API_KEY", "\"${properties.getProperty(" MAPS_API_KEY ")}\"")

    } 

    buildTypes {
            // set buildConfig to true
            android.buildFeatures.buildConfig = true
            debug {
                isMinifyEnabled = true // optional, set to true
            }
            release {
                isMinifyEnabled = true // optional, set to true
                proguardFiles(
                    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                    "proguard-rules.pro"
                )
            }
        }

...
```

Final personal thoughts:

- Set **isMinifyEnabled** true, as this makes rewrites the source code of your app, making it hard for attacker to read it.
- I find it a good practice to store api keys in the server, I find this more secure, when you also have secure server rules set.

I hope this helps, happy coding!