# No internet permission but the permission is given, when i intilize the admob banner (it give a red underlying saying i dont have permission)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, admob

I get this missing `"Missing permissions required by BaseAdView.loadAd: android.permission.INTERNET"` when i copy pasted the meta tags that are needed for the google maps sdk, without them it doesn't show the error. What could be the issue and the fix?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*******">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SmartQ">
        <activity
            android:name=".mapp"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".sdkmaps"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".map"
            android:exported="false" />
        <!--
             TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

             To get one, follow the directions here:

                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

             Once you have your API key (it starts with "AIza"), define a new property in your
             project's local.properties file (e.g. MAPS_API_KEY=Aiza...), and replace the
             "YOUR_API_KEY" string in this file with "${MAPS_API_KEY}".
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Web_view"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Update1"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="*******" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTqWY.png)

Comment: No internet permission but the permission is given. error only on the line where admob banner is intilized  those codes looks like this  mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest1);

Comment: under load adrequest it give a red underline but its going away when i remove the 1st  meta tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that android is unable to resolve `${MAPS_API_KEY}`.

The easiest fix is replacing `${MAPS_API_KEY}` with real key directly in manifest, something like:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBdJ88HN7LTGkHHK5whfaVv8a5ozlx2E_k" />
```

If you anyway want to store your key in .properties file, follow this answer:
[How to store maps api key in local.properties and use it in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340503/how-to-store-maps-api-key-in-local-properties-and-use-it-in-androidmanifest-xml)